# Select text in a string and convert into a table in python

Tags: python, string

I have this string:

```
String='''
    service {'name': 'services'}
    enable yes
    frequency 7200
    service {'name': 'files'}
    enable yes
    frequency 6000
    none
'''
```

and I'm looking the way to convert in a table like that:

```
table = [[services, yes, 7200],
[files, yes, 6000]]
```

And always in the last row there is this "none" telling is the end of the string, just ignore this row to the table.
Any module or function to do it?

Comment: There are many ways to do this.  If you post an attempt at parsing this, you will probably get more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to parse it yourself.

You can use the `re` module to write regex to do this, or you may even just use the string method `startswith`.

You can loop through, and on seeing `line.strip().startswith('service')` you can pop the right side off and use the `json` module and do `json.loads(rightside)`, and do a lookup on the key `name`.

After you find that, enter in a code path to expect `startswith('enable')` and `startswith('frequency'`), then take the right side and parse it. You can also use a multiline regex that finds all of:

```
r'^\s*service (.*)$\n^\s*enable (\w+)$^\s*frequency (\d+)$'
```

I haven't used a multiline regex in a while, but some pattern like that should work.

To summarize, implement with `startswith` and write your own logic to do this, or run it through a multiline regex. Either way, it will probably be best to use the `json` module to grab the service name.